# How to use twitter log-in on a website

Tags: twitter, authentication

How can I use Twitter authentication to allow users to sign in to my website (for example, by using, for example, the "Sign-in with twitter" button on my website)?
Any site references or APIs would be useful.

Comment: Do you mean using twitters Api? Or just html button?

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: You may find this helpful, if you can't implement it through twitters documentation [Oauth](http://devcenter.kinvey.com/html5/tutorials/how-to-implement-safe-signin-via-oauth)

Answer (score -1):

You need to use Twitter's `OAUTH` capability. Read Twitter's [Implementing Sign in with Twitter](https://dev.twitter.com/web/sign-in/implementing) documentation on their developer website.